# Floor implementation

Tags: code-golf, floating-point

Target:
Write a `floor()` function from scratch.

Manipulating like converting float to string, and cutting all after dot are allowed.

All languages are allowed.

Any usage of built in language functions (like `toInteger()`) or similar is not allowed, casting operators are not allowed.

So, your task is implement floor() function without using casting and built in language functions.

Your function must support at least max 32-bit integer values (you will never receive negative values).

Forced casting (like `somevar as float`) and normal casting - such as`(int) somevar` -
 is not allowed, any built in functions, not allowed, all other stuff allowed.

Winner: Shortest implemention.

Comment: This is severely underspecified. **1.** Which input range do we have to support. In particular, can the input be negative? **2.** What exactly does *built in language functions(like tointeger()) or something like this* mean? I assume casting to integer is forbidden as well, but what about operations that simply return an integer (e.g., integer division by 1)? **3.** C returns an integral floating point number, not an integer. Any hypothetical `tointeger()` would probably do something else.

Comment: @Dennis, sorry for underspecifies. I fix some problems of question

Comment: Casting is still unclear. Unless we are forced to return an integral float, we'll have to cast at some point. Also, does *max int32 values* refer to the maximal signed or the maximal unsigned integer? It might be clearer if you just state the limits in decimal.

Comment: @Dennis, fixed all

Comment: Can the result have a leading dot and zeroes (eg `5.67` -> `5.00`)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 57 bytes

```c
i;int f(float n){for(i=-2147483648;i<=n;i++);return i-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#U87MS84pTUlVsCkuScnM18uw@59pnZlXopCmkZaTn1iikKdZnZZfpJFpa2CdaWObZ52pra1pXZRaUlqUp5Cpa2hd@z83MTNPI1GzmouzoAioM01DSTUlJk9JJ03DWM9AU9Mam7ihiaGpJUiu9j8A) (it takes too long, so I changed it to start from `0`.

Comment: I think you could save a byte by using `0x80000000` instead of `-2147483648`

Comment: Nice work.
It working and seems interesting.

Comment: You could also do `i++<=n;` instead

Comment: `negative values not important`, so is' default can be 0

Comment: You can remove the `int` return type from the function definition - the compiler will default to `int` if no other type is given.

Comment: `1<<32-1` == `-2147483648`

Comment: Or even shorter: `5<<31`

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
q'.%0=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@orqdqYPv/v6GJsaGxkZ6ppaWlsREA)

I found several 6 bytes solution but I can't do less than this.

Comment: "Manipulating like converting float to string, and cutting all after dot are allowed."

Comment: @LeakyNun "are allowed" means that I can do that, doesn't it?

Comment: Oops, I misread it...

Comment: "Any usage of built in language functions (like toInteger()) or similar is not allowed"

Comment: @monobogdan I haven't used any of those. I'm reading the input `q`, splitting where the point is `'.%` and taking the part before the point `0=`

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 6 chars

```
x=>~~x
```

Test:

```js
f = x=>~~x

document.addEventListener('input', event => {
  var x = event.target.valueAsNumber
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = x + " => " + f(x)
})
```

```html
<input type=number> <output></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>21</s> 13 bytes

```python
lambda x:x//1
```

Outputs a float if input is float, outputs an integer if input is integer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYVWhr2/4vzwjMydVIaSoNNWKi7OgKDOvRCFNIzOvoLREQ1Pzv6GRMZehibGhsZGeqaWlpbERlyGXAZeBniGXIRAb6BkAaQMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
|0
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=fDA=&input=MTIzLjc4OQ==)

---

### Alternative

```
ÂU
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=wlU=&input=MTIzLjc4OQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 53 bytes

```
@for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("%1")do @echo %%a
```

*Trims everything after `.`*